# Deriving the tangential directional derivative of a scalar function on a parametric surface

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

Given are a parametric surface $S(u,v) = \big( x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v) \big)$ and a scalar function $f(u,v)$, both defined on the same domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. As such, we can associate every point on the surface $S(u,v)$ with a scalar value $f(u,v)$. Throughout, it is assumed that the surface is regular and the function $f$ differentiable. ​

Out of curiosity, I'm interested in deriving an expression for the tangential directional derivative of the function $f$ as seen from the surface $S(u,v)$, which I'll denote $\tilde{f}$. That is, considering a point $p = S(u,v)$ and a nearby point $q = S(u+ha, v+hb)$ with $h$ variable and for some (domain) direction $w = \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$, what is the result of

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\tilde{f}(q) - \tilde{f}(p)}{\|q-p\|}.$$

Below I've written down my approach — **the question is whether the result is correct** (I do have some doubts about it, as explained below).

As the *numerator* is the difference of two function values, it is equivalent to $f(u+ha, v+hb) - f(u,v)$. Substituting the expressions for $p$ and $q$, the *denominator* is $\| S(u+ha, v+hb) - S(u,v) \|$. From the *Taylor expansion*, we know that $S(u+ha, v+hb) \approx S(u,v) + ha \frac{\partial S}{\partial u}(u,v) + hb \frac{\partial S}{\partial v}(u,v)$ for small $h$, which in the limit becomes an equivalence. As such, in the limit the denominator represents the length of a tangent vector I'll denote $h \tilde{w}$. Introducing the $3 \times 2$ *Jacobian matrix* $J = \big(\frac{\partial S}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial S}{\partial v}\big)$, we can express this tangent vector as $h \tilde{w} = h J w$.

We can now re-write the above as

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\tilde{f}(q) - \tilde{f}(p)}{\| q - p \|} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(u+ha, v+hb) - f(u,v)}{h} \frac{h}{\| q - p \|} = D_w f(u,v) \frac{1}{\| \tilde{w} \|} = \frac{\nabla f \cdot w}{\| \tilde{w} \|},$$

where $D_w f(u,v)$ is the directional derivative of $f(u,v)$ in the direction of $w$. Next, with $\tilde {w} = J w$, we have $w = J^+ \tilde{w}$, with $J^+$ the (left) *Moore-Penrose inverse*. That is, $J^+ = (J^TJ)^{-1} J^T$. Introducing the *first fundamental form* (i.e. the *metric tensor*) $g = J^TJ$, we can write $J^+ = g^{-1} J^T$. Therefore, we have

$$\frac{\nabla f \cdot w}{\| \tilde{w} \|} = \frac{ \left(\nabla f\right)^T g^{-1} J^T \tilde{w}}{\| \tilde{w} \|} = \left( J g^{-1} \nabla f \right) \cdot \frac{\tilde{w}}{\| \tilde{w} \|},$$

which follows from transposing (recall that $g$ is symmetric and therefore $g^{-1}$ is as well).

On the one hand, this looks promising, as $J g^{-1} \nabla f$ matches what I've seen described as the *tangential gradient* (also referred to as the *surface gradient*) in the literature. Therefore, like the ordinary directional derivative, the tangential directional derivative appears to be the dot product of a gradient and a direction vector. On the other hand, I'm a bit sceptical about this vector appearing *normalised*. Is this a result of using this specific approach, or did I make a mistake/wrong assumption somewhere along the way?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that way because you are dividing by the (infinitesimal) distance along the surface, $\|q-p\|$. To get the derivative depending on the length of the vector (and hence the "velocity" with which you transverse the curve) you should start with
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\tilde{f}(q) - \tilde{f}(p)}{h}.
$$

Even if you don't do it over a surface and stay on the plane (say $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$), if you start dividing by the distance between the points

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi((x,y)+h(a,b)) - \phi(x,y)}{\|h(a,b)\|}.
$$

you will get something that depends only on the direction of $(a,b)$ and not its modulus. You should start with

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi((x,y)+h(a,b)) - \phi(x,y)}{h}.
$$
instead.